# How to paint with button click

Tags: java, swing

how to call a paintComponent when a mouse click ?

Comment: Maybe start by looking [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score 1):

> how to pass my values by button click?

How do you change text in a JLabel or a JButton? You use the setText(...) method.

So how do you display the celsius value in your DisplayPanel?

Well you create a `setCelsius(...)` method in your DisplayPanel class. In that method you save the celsius value as an instance variable in your class and you invoke repaint().

Then in your `paintComponent()` method you use the saved celcius to do your custom painting.

So in your ActionListner you calculate the Celsius and then invoke

```
displayPanel.setCelsius( Celsius );
```

Comment: I am so confused with setCelsius method in display panel. Can you please give me little more details ? Further more I want to run my validations also.

Comment: As you can see that I am retrieving data and storing in variables within actionPerformed() should I move that to somewhere else ?

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html) for a working example. Download the code and play with it. Notice how there is a class called "MyPanel" that contains the painting code? Well you need to create a class called "DisplayPanel" for your painting code. Then you can also add a method called "setCelsius(...)" to that class. Now you can pass a parameter to your DisplayPanel class and then do your custom painting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling displayPanel.setBackground(new Color(r, g, b))? You should also remove the

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

}//paintComponent();
```

and just use `JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();`

Comment: But I want to draw a graph also thats why I am using the paint component.
Should I remove that still ?

Comment: The paintComponent method is alredy implemented in the Component class, which JPanel extends. You'll probably never need to override it.